# Query for taking data between two specific months and two specific year in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I want to get data between From Month1 year1 to Month2 year2

Example From Jan 2016 to Jan 2017.

I have the query like

```
select * from customer cr where 
 EXTRACT(MONTH FROM cr.regdate) between Month1 and Month2 AND 
 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cr.regdate) between Year1 and Year2
```

This query is giving wrong result when I would like to take the data from Jan 2016 to Jan 2017. I will be expecting the data from jan 2016, Feb 2016, Mar 2016 till Jan 2017.
But it is giving the result only for Jan 2016 and Jan 2017. Please guide me.

Comment: `where regdate between date '2016-01-01' and date '2017-01-01'`

Comment: My input parameters are Month1, Year1, Month2, Year2. I am selecting the values from Month drop down and year drop down.

Comment: And? Simply build the appropriate date value from those values. If you were using an up-to-date Postgres version you could use `make_date(year, month, 1)` for that.